# How to express the notion of taking min of content and fixed value for scrollable element?

Tags: html, css, sizing

Just for simplicity sake let's say that my fixed height is 100px. Then the question from title could be expressed in CSS as the following:

```
  height: min(min-content, 100px);
```

Meaning take min -- either content height or 100px. The only problem is, it is not supported.

I could skip `height` and use `max/min-height` properties, but then I lose the ability to scroll. So how to express this notion and still have ability to scroll the content?

Here is actual markup I use (I need this nested structure with 3 divs):

```html
<div style="position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:10rem;
            
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: min-content;">
    <div style="position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;">
        <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow-y: auto;">
            <div>A</div>
            <div>B</div>
            <div>C</div>
            <div>D</div>
            <div>E</div>
            <div>F</div>
            <div>G</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach which can be solution in some cases is not to focus on height directly, but changing the way the container is displayed -- the key is flexbox here.

```html
<div style="position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:10rem;
    display:flex;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100px;">
    <div style="position: relative;
        width: 100%;">
        <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow-y: auto;">
            <div>A</div>                  
            <div>B</div>
            <div>C</div>
            <div>D</div>
            <div>E</div>
            <div>F</div>
            <div>G</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** it is not universal solution (for example it does work in dialogs, because dialog are displayed as block).